# flexslider not working on acquia drupal cloud

Tags: drupal, flexslider, acquia

I've been able to get flexslider module + library to work on local dev instances of core drupal in the past, but when I try to enable/configure for acquia cloud, it inserts the images as li's but does not animate them

The steps I've taken- -Installed/enabled the flexslider module on my local dev environment -downloaded and installed the latest flexslider library from github into docroot/sites/all/libraries/flexslider/ -git added/committed/pushed the changes to acquia cloud -enabled the module in the acquia cloud dev environment -edited the 'basic page' content type to use a flexslider field -created a basic page with a few images in that field

As stated above, the images get inserted as list items but do not get animated. It seems like the module is being invoked, but the flexslider js files are not being included in the .

The page in question: http://acquiacloudwwedev.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boneheaded mistake on my part - In the default option set for FlexSlider, I had the "Move" field set to 0. This apparently makes it not animate. Changing it to "1" resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have a module called rotating_banner which is causing javascript errors and getting in the way of anything else running. Try turning of this module and giving it a go.

Comment: thanks for the response, pete -  I tried using rotating_banner module after,  so my flexslider issue was present before that, and is still present now that I've removed the rotating_banner block from that page to simplify things